# Editing a field of an object in array with redux and input fields

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am fetching list of items from api and show them in table whose some fields are editable. When I am fetched items, I put them into redux store since I need to show and edit them in different pages.
For example let's say my object is like this:

```
[
  {
    "test_cases": {
      "acceptableFailureCodes": [],
      "applicationNames": [],
      "caseId": "22e809c3-c6fb-49e5-b57f-3f7ccea3d2a0",
      "client": "web",
      "count": 12,
      "dependentCase": [],
      "endpointByApplication": "",
      "formDataRequests": [],
      "formattedJsonBody": "",
      "formattedUrl": "https://example-url",
      "header": {
        "header": [],
        "map": []
      },
      "host": "test.com",
      "isDependent": false,
      "isMedia": false,
      "isOriginal": true,
      "isUsedInCollection": false,
      "jsonBody": "",
      "map": [],
      "maxWaitTime": 1,
      "method": "PUT",
      "minWaitTime": 1,
      "queryParams": "no param",
      "taskId": "5e684b46-b8f0-4598-947e-ea100db2a406",
      "url": "https://example-url-2",
      "weight": 0
    },
    "collection:"Some other fields...."
  },
  {
    "test_cases": {
      "acceptableFailureCodes": [],
      "applicationNames": [],
      "caseId": "7b2fd8ce-fc36-414e-b38d-2ff5d894be83",
      "client": "web",
      "count": 2,
      "dependentCase": [],
      "endpointByApplication": "",
      "formDataRequests": [
        {
          "dataType": "File",
          "key": "testKey",
          "value": "testValue"
        }
      ],
      "formattedJsonBody": "",
      "formattedUrl": "https://example-url-3,
      "header": {
        "header": [],
        "map": []
      },
      "host": "test.com",
      "isDependent": false,
      "isMedia": false,
      "isOriginal": true,
      "isUsedInCollection": false,
      "jsonBody": "",
      "label": "test",
      "map": [],
      "maxWaitTime": 1,
      "method": "POST",
      "minWaitTime": 1,
      "queryParams": "no param",
      "taskId": "5e684b46-b8f0-4598-947e-ea100db2a406",
      "url": "https://example-url",
      "weight": 0
    },
    "collection:"Some other fields...."
  }
]
```

And those are the fields that I am editing in different pages with a form like this.

```
applicationNames // --> this is an array.
minWaitTime,
maxWaitTime,
method
...
```

[image]

So I have 2 question in here.

1. Should I write a different action for each field update in this array?
2. I put some input fields to update fields. Should I directly update store or first update internal state of component and at the submit of form put change into the store?

Comment: 1. if there are not many states to update , you can do it.
2. Or you can define an object containing all the changes like {applicationName :[] ,method:'',...} and update the redux when you handle onClick or onSubmit event